# Differences between American and British question intonation?

Tags: american-english, british-english, transatlantic-differences, intonation

In interactions with American and British people, I've noted Americans tend to have rise-fall (↗↘) intonation while I've heard the British having rise-fall-rise (↗↘↗) intonation while asking questions. I've heard both use simple rising intonation (↗) for questions as well as upspeak in general. Anyone else observed this before?

Comment: Rising intonation is known as [Australian Question Intonation](https://www.google.co.uk/?gws_rd=ssl#q=australian%20question%20intonation) (AQI). I've never noticed rise-fall or rise-fall-rise.